# Multiple choice menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble creating a menu with multiple choices and I'm hoping this great forum can help.

The webpage in question is:

> http://rrg.genesis-unlimited.com/solutions/?categories=Adventure%20Park&level=1&format=video

The site is being built in wordpress using the catalyst theme framework which is very similar to Genesis.

I'm using the "views" plugin to create multiple areas.

First you have your main section where you choose the main category, in this case:

```
Adventure Park
Arborist / Tree Climbing
etc.. 
there are 7 main categories.
```

Then there are 3 subcategories: `"Beginner, Intermediate, advanced"`

Each category / sub-category choice has it's own page.

For instance `"Adventure Park - Beginner"` has a different page than `"Adventure Park - intermediate"` and so does `"Arborist / Tree Climbing - Beginner"`.

The content of each page will also have 3 sections for video, articles and FAQ's.

There are basically 28 pages in all with each one having it's own content.  This is a big undertaking.

My dilemma is that I would like to allow this choice without the use of a drop down menu.

I'd like the user to be able to click on the first level choice and then the second level choice which will be displayed below it.

Here's a screen shot of what I want it to look like, hopefully the visual helps:

http://rrg.genesis-unlimited.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ishot-1.jpg

So you can see where you can click on the top level category and then choose the second level "view".

Anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this using wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for plugins,if you dont find anyone then if you know css go and change the css file

Comment: I have looked all over for plugins and have found nothing, not even paid.  I know CSS well and that isn't a solution here as far as I can tell.  Perhaps if the "beginner / Intermediate / advanced" options only showed up once they clicked on the first main option?  I'm not sure how I would do that...